# Neo4j Cypher performance optimization on the query

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have the following query (automatically generated):

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -3})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Vacancy ) -[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode:Requirable) 
WHERE ceNode.id in [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
WITH DISTINCT childD, rdgd, dg, collect(ceNode) as ceNodes 
with childD, dg, rdgd, 
apoc.coll.toSet(reduce(ceNodeLabels = [], n IN ceNodes | ceNodeLabels + labels(n))) as ceNodeLabels 
WHERE all(x IN ['Employment', 'Location'] WHERE x IN ceNodeLabels) 
WITH childD  
WHERE  (childD.`active` = true)  AND ( (childD.`salaryUsd` >= 5492)  OR  (childD.`hourlyRateUsd` >= 124) ) 
WITH childD  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN [16, 18, 4, 21, 22, 7, 8, 9, 14] 
WITH childD, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
WITH childD , toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInteger(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes  
WHERE weight > 0 
WITH childD, weight, totalVotes 
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -3})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, u, ru , weight, totalVotes  
ORDER BY  totalVotes DESC, childD.createdAt DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10 
RETURN childD AS decision, dg, rdgd, u, ru, weight, totalVotes, 
[ (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS weightedCriteria , 
[ (c1t:Translation)<-[rc1t:CONTAINS]-(c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) WHERE c1t.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(c1.id), translation: c1t} ] AS weightedCriteriaTranslations , 
[ (childD)-[:REQUIRES]->(ce:CompositeEntity) | {entity: ce} ] AS decisionCompositeEntities, 
[ (childD)-[:REQUIRES]->(ce:CompositeEntity)-[:CONTAINS]->(trans:Translation) WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(id(ce)), translation: trans} ] AS decisionCompositeEntitiesTranslations, 
[ (childD)-[:CONTAINS]->(trans:Translation) WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(childD.id), translation: trans} ] AS decisionTranslations
```

Right now query takes ~2 sec to complete on 10k `childD` nodes

Is there something I may refactor in the query in order to improve the execution time?

This is an execution plan:

**Cypher version: CYPHER 4.4, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 2929280 total db hits in 1908 ms**

**SVG version**: https://files.fm/u/pwpygthj5

[image]

**UPDATED**

```
PROFILE MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -3})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Vacancy )-[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode:Requirable) 
WHERE ceNode.id in [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
WITH childD , collect(ceNode) as ceNodes with childD , 
apoc.coll.toSet(reduce(ceNodeLabels = [], n IN ceNodes | ceNodeLabels + labels(n))) as ceNodeLabels WHERE all(x IN ['Employment', 'Location'] WHERE x IN ceNodeLabels) 
WITH childD  
WHERE ( (childD.`salaryUsd` >= 4436)  OR  (childD.`hourlyRateUsd` >= 194) ) AND  (childD.`active` = true)  
WITH childD  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24] 
WITH childD, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
WITH childD , toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInteger(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes  
WHERE weight > 0  
WITH childD, weight, totalVotes  
ORDER BY  totalVotes DESC, childD.createdAt DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10 
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -3})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)  
RETURN childD AS decision, dg, rdgd, u, ru, weight, totalVotes, 
[ (c1:Criterion)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS weightedCriteria , 
[ (c1t:Translation)<-[rc1t:CONTAINS]-(c1:Criterion)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) WHERE c1t.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(c1.id), translation: c1t} ] AS weightedCriteriaTranslations , 
[ (childD)-[:REQUIRES]->(ce:CompositeEntity) | {entity: ce} ] AS decisionCompositeEntities, 
[ (childD)-[:REQUIRES]->(ce:CompositeEntity)-[:CONTAINS]->(trans:Translation) WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(id(ce)), translation: trans} ] AS decisionCompositeEntitiesTranslations, 
[ (childD)-[:CONTAINS]->(role:Role)<-[:CONTAINS]-(user:User {uuid: 'e1f4b9f7-f1ec-4f6d-83f4-f0233d6cb85b'}) | {role: role} ] AS decisionUserRoles, 
[ (childD)-[:CONTAINS]->(trans:Translation) WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(childD.id), translation: trans} ] AS decisionTranslations
```

**Cypher version: CYPHER 4.4, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 614531 total db hits in 520 ms.**

**SVG execution plan:** https://files.fm/u/2z8dfxbr5

Comment: I cannot see the image very well since it is low resolution. Can you capture the execution plan into multiple images? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, thank you. I uploaded SVG version here https://files.fm/u/pwpygthj5

Comment: Thanks @Alexanoid.  Do you see the 1.1M db hits with the keyword CONTAINS? Let's start from there.

Comment: Thank you! You were right - I optimized `CONTAINS` and now the query works better, but still not perfect. Could you please take a look on the updated version in the question? Also move `DecisionGroup`  after the `SKIP`

Comment: Also, I have to execute this query two times - one for count because of the pagination and then for the actual data

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts when looking at your query:

if the collections of nodeIds , like in

```
WHERE ceNode.id in [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

are also part of the dynamically created cypher, you may consider using parameters. In that case, Neo4j does not have to create a new query plan every time.

in this part

```
WITH DISTINCT childD, rdgd, dg, collect(ceNode) as ceNodes
```

you do not need the `DISTINCT` because that happens automatically since you have the `COLLECT()`

Comment: everything is in parameters right now, this is just debug output of the query

Comment: Also, I removed DISTINCT as you suggested. What else can be improved there?

Answer (score 1):

I see that line 16 has 1.1M db hits in the query execution plan and it is a duplication of line 1.

```
line 01: MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -3})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Vacancy ) -[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode:Requirable) 

line 16: MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -3})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD)
```

It is not needed because the childD that you get from line 1 will be the same with line 16 and it is contained by the same DecisionGroup with id=-3. Try removing it and see if the result is the same as before.

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -3})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Vacancy ) -[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode:Requirable) 
WHERE ceNode.id in [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
WITH DISTINCT childD, rdgd, dg, collect(ceNode) as ceNodes 
with childD, dg, rdgd, 
apoc.coll.toSet(reduce(ceNodeLabels = [], n IN ceNodes | ceNodeLabels + labels(n))) as ceNodeLabels 
WHERE all(x IN ['Employment', 'Location'] WHERE x IN ceNodeLabels) 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd  
WHERE  (childD.`active` = true)  AND ( (childD.`salaryUsd` >= 5492)  OR  (childD.`hourlyRateUsd` >= 124) ) 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN [16, 18, 4, 21, 22, 7, 8, 9, 14] 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInteger(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes  
WHERE weight > 0 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, weight, totalVotes 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, u, ru , weight, totalVotes  
ORDER BY  totalVotes DESC, childD.createdAt DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10 
RETURN childD AS decision, dg, rdgd, u, ru, weight, totalVotes, 
[ (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS weightedCriteria , 
[ (c1t:Translation)<-[rc1t:CONTAINS]-(c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) WHERE c1t.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(c1.id), translation: c1t} ] AS weightedCriteriaTranslations , 
[ (childD)-[:REQUIRES]->(ce:CompositeEntity) | {entity: ce} ] AS decisionCompositeEntities, 
[ (childD)-[:REQUIRES]->(ce:CompositeEntity)-[:CONTAINS]->(trans:Translation) WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(id(ce)), translation: trans} ] AS decisionCompositeEntitiesTranslations, 
[ (childD)-[:CONTAINS]->(trans:Translation) WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {entityId: toInteger(childD.id), translation: trans} ] AS decisionTranslations
```